# docker COPY and Windows Directory Junction (symlinks)

Tags: docker, directory, dockerfile, symlink

How is the docker `COPY` command supposed to work when there is a windows directory junction in the directory you are copying?

---

**More Details...**

Older docker versions (<18.0) seem to copy the contents of the directory junction to the target directory. Newer versions (18.0) seem to copy the symlink itself, and if the link target does not exist in the container, the link will be invalid.

For more background, my directory structure looks something like this:

```
C:\Project>dir .
02/06/2018  08:38 AM    <DIR>          .
02/06/2018  08:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/05/2018  07:09 PM             4,002 program.py
02/05/2018  07:09 PM             123   Dockerfile
01/29/2018  10:50 PM    <JUNCTION>     mylib [C:\Lib\mylib]
```

The `Dockerfile` command looks like this:

```
COPY . /home/foo
```

I would expect the `COPY` command to copy `program.py` and the contents of `mylib` into the container (and this is what happened on older docker versions), but newer docker images copy the junction itself.

Comment: Did you find a solution?